# Ubuntu 19.04 + Gnome 3.32 = How to get dynamic transparency to dock and top bar back?

Tags: gnome, dock, transparency

Can somebody help with getting dynamic transparency to dock and top bar back please? I found some gnome extensions but only for top bar and I want it to work for both (dock and top bar). In Ubuntu 18.10 + Gnome 3.30 this already worked quite well. Why is this nice feature removed?

Answer (score 2):

*Edit 2019-05-17*: as of Ubuntu 19.04, the Dynamic transparency feature of Dash To Dock does not seem to work. You can set a custum, fixed opacity only.
*end edit*

As the feature has been removed, you will need to adjust transparency separately for the dock and for the top bar, and play with the settings for each of the items to make them match

**Dock**
The easiest way is to install the Gnome Shell extension Dash to Dock. Ubuntu Dock is based on Dash to Dock and uses the same settings. However, Dash to Dock`exposes plenty of configuration options that allow you, among others, to set dynamic transparency. You can easily install Dash to Dock with the terminal command`sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-dashtodock`.

To enable the extension and access the configuration settings, make sure you have Gnome Tweaks (or just "Tweaks") installed. On the extensions tab of Tweak, you can enable or disable the installed extensions. Click on the cog next to an extension to customize.

In the Dash to Dock options, you will find the option to customize transparency (or opacity) on the "Appearance" tab. Next to "Custom opacity", you can turn on dynamic opacity.

Finally, make sure you disable either Dash to Dock or Ubuntu Dock. Otherwise, you will be running two docks.

**Top bar**

Because it is a feature removed from the stock Gnome Shell, one can bring the feature back in with a Gnome Extension. The fully updated Gnome Shell extension [Dynamic Panel Transparency](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1011/dynamic-panel-transparency/) will fill your needs.

As the extension is not included in the default software source, you need to install it from the website. This is not possible in a default Ubuntu install. As I did not locate another Askubuntu post that may describe how to enable the installation of extensions from the [Gnome extensions website](https://extensions.gnome.org/local/), I mention it briefly here:

1. Install the host connector. You can do this easily in de terminal with the command `sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell`
2. Install the gnome shell integration in your browser. The procedure depends on the browser you use.

Now, you should be able to install an extension merely by clicking the "On/Off" button on the extension's site.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, Dash to Dock and Dynamic Panel Transparency together are the best workaround for this feature (not perfect because Dash to Dock seems not supporting dynamic transparency in Gnome 3.32 - when I choose it allways switch back to fixed transparency itself while on The top bar dynamic transparency works just perfect). So finaly this two extensions give me best possible solution for now. Thank you.

Comment: Indeed, in 19.04 dynamic transparency of Dash To Dock does not appear to work as expected!

Answer (score 1):

**Dock transparency**

This helped me:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock transparency-mode 'FIXED'
```

This command will set transparency to 80% (change it as you need):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock background-opacity 0.2
```

To reset default settings:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock background-opacity
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock background-opacity
```

Comment: Works great for me with Ubuntu 19.10

Answer (score 0):

The ubuntu dock is a customised verion of the [dash to dock extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/). You can install it to tweak various things among which the dynamic transparency for the dock.

Comment: This is not making the top bar transparent? Because that is also what the user asks.

Comment: That is correct, but OP said that he already found an extension for the top bar so I thought it redundant to include the information again. If needed I'll expand the answer though.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, Dash to Dock extension is almost perfect but on Ubuntu 19.04 I cannot use Dynamic transparency because it always switch back to fixed itself. So I set transparency to nice compromis and now I can live with it.